# How can I start Google Chrome on OS X with the --allow-files-access-from-files argument?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, osx-snow-leopard

I'm running Google Chrome (12.0.742.122) on OS X (Snow Leopard) and I need to pass the "--allow-files-access-from-files" option so that I can test some local javascript stuff I'm working on.

I've tried using the following command-line approaches:

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Content/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --allow-files-access-from-files

open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Content/MacOS/Google\ Chrome -n --args --allow-files-access-from-files
```

Both will launch Google Chrome but it doesn't seem to take the argument as I am still not able to test my local Javascript.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
open -a "Google Chrome" --args --allow-file-access-from-files
```

I don't know how to adequately test the `--allow-file-access-from-files` switch, but it works for `--incognito` for me (same version and OS).

It appears as though Chrome does not like to be opened twice; when passing the `-n` switch to `open` (which is supposed to open a new instance), it immediately kills itself.

EDIT: 'allow-files-access-from-files' should be 'allow-file-access-from-files'

Comment: still doesn't work for me.

Comment: Does the incognito switch work?

Comment: I just did a system restart (had some updates to install) and now Chrome is working. thanks.

Comment: FYI - it's actually `open -a "Google Chrome" --args --allow-file-access-from-files`.  You have an extra `'s'` in there.

Comment: @w3rthl3ss what is this witchcraft?  I typed that *exact* command (although with a different option) and got *unrecognized option* but when I copy/paste your command and replace the option with mine, it works! I have two commands right next to each other, they look identical, but only one of them works!